# SSRS - Excel export with multiple worksheets showing different report/different query results (Possible??)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So I have this situation where I have a report that will require the Excel export to generate a spreadsheet that has multiple sheets where the first sheet will show the main report data (everything) and the preceding sheets will have a slightly modified report.

For example, the first report will have a list of all complaints that have been filed by the customers that'll contain complainant's name, date of complaint, description of complaint, complaint investigator, complaint violation # (this is null or has a value), complaint cleared date, street address, city, state, zipcode.

For the following sheets that come after main report (one the first sheet), I would like group the following data based on the complain investigator.  In those sheets being grouped by the investigator, I only want to then display the date of complaint, a count of how many complaints were filled on that date & a count of how many complaint violations have a value.

**Again, I don't need help with the queries, I just want to know if it's possible to have different reports/queries on individual sheets in the excel export**.  I've tried looking for documentation on how to do this, but all I'm finding is grouping by and only slimming down the main report on all the sheets that come after, not running a different report/query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For what I wanted to achieve, this solution solved my problem (minus the last sentence, don't need a navigation pane):

https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/122169/ssrs-concern.html

Comment: Links can be broken, if you want to post an answer copy the instructions and then reference the page. I'll reverse the downvote once you update your answer.